# Ethernet shield compatibility

Tags: ethernet-shield

Does anyone know if there is an Ethernet shield is compatible with the Arduino Ethernet shield (R3)? The R3 does not seem to be in production anymore and I need a replacement shield. Found some from Velleman, or maybe Ethernet Shield 2?

- [Arduino Ethernet Shield R3](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-ethernet-shield-without-poe-module)
- [Arduino Ethernet Shield 2](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-ethernet-shield-2)
- [Velleman Ethernet Shield](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=412244)

Comment: Will you kindly provide a link to the Velleman shield?

Comment: Added links to the boards

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not compatible.  It uses the ENC28J60 chip from Microchip, whereas the others all use the W5100 Wiznet chip. A very different chip.

You can use it if you refactor all your code to use the [Ethercard library](https://github.com/jcw/ethercard) instead of the Ethernet library.

There are cheap Chinese (or other far east) clones of the Ethernet Shields, that use the W5100 (or a counterfeit copy) that people have varying amounts of luck with if you really need W5100 compatibility. I have one, but have had problems with it starting up properly sometimes and needs a bit of a kick with the reset button.

Comment: UIPEthernet library https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip for the ENC28J60. I didn't try it yet